# How to run a loop for a specified amount of time

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

I would like to run a piece of code for a specified amount of time. This does not seem to work. Why?

```
int sec = 5;
auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
while (std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(
          start - std::chrono::steady_clock::now()
       ).count() < sec * 1000)
{
    // do stuff
};
```

Comment: The loop does not seem to terminate.

Comment: It runs longer than 5 sec.

Comment: `now` is later than `start`. Please review your subtraction

Comment: Well, maybe somebody will find this helpful anyways. I found my answer, so I am happy.

Comment: @uneven_mark: While the question is trivial, it's not off-topic. Very often the bugs we find in people's code is not really at the core of their domain-specific considerations but something much simpler and sillier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Your specific issues

Your problem seems to be a reversed subtraction: The loop execution duration is `now() - start`, not `start - now()`.

By the way, a little code beautification for you to consider:

```
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    auto work_duration = 5s;
    auto start = now();
    while ( (now() - start) < work_duration)
    {
        // do stuff
    };
}
```

(and this [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/9DNcPD) - which is something you should make sure happens for the code in your questions...)

#### Generalization

Let's go a little further, and create a generic function for you for running something for a certain duration:

```
#include <chrono>

template <typename F, typename Duration>
void timed_repeat(F f, Duration execution_duration)
{
    auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now;
    auto stop_time = now() + execution_duration;
    while (now() < stop_time) { f(); };
}

int main() {
    auto work_duration = std::chrono::seconds{5};
    auto foo = []() {
        // whatever 
    };
    timed_repeat(foo, work_duration);
}
```

**Important note:** Remember that the work duration is "gross" rather than "net", i.e. if your process is preempted by other processes, or just sleeps on I/O, that still counts towards the time spent running the `//whatever` part. That's true both for your original code snippet and for mine.

Comment: Well, now I feel smart :D
Makes total sense. Sorry to bother